# Timing chain for a sunfire

Tags: engine

Exhaust , intake & the other one at the bottom are lined up when I start after a full rotation they are not, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: how's the chain tension? you should turn the motor over twice by hand before starting the motor as well.

Comment: you did 2 rotations right?  remember the cam rotates once for every 2 rotations of the crank.

Comment: What is the make model year and engine.